# Python gzip folder structure when zipping single file

Tags: python, gzip, directory

I'm using Python's gzip module to gzip content for a single file, using code similar to the example in the docs:

```
import gzip
content = "Lots of content here"
f = gzip.open('/home/joe/file.txt.gz', 'wb')
f.write(content)
f.close()
```

If I open the gz file in 7-zip, I see a folder hierarchy matching the path I wrote the gz to and my content is nested several folders deep, like /home/joe in the example above, or C: -> Documents and Settings -> etc in Windows.

How can I get the one file that I'm zipping to just be in the root of the gz file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you will have to use `GzipFile` directly:

```
import gzip
content = "Lots of content here"
real_f = open('/home/joe/file.txt.gz', 'wb')
f = gzip.GZipFile('file.txt.gz', fileobj=real_f)
f.write(content)
f.close()
real_f.close()
```

It looks like `open` doesn't allow you to specify the `fileobj` separate from the filename.

Comment: Any idea why I am getting this error?

    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GZipFile'

Comment: Try GzipFile instead.

Answer (score 2):

You must use [`gzip.GzipFile`](http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html) and supply a `fileobj`. If you do that, you can specify an arbitrary filename for the header of the gz file.

Comment: Any idea why I am getting this error? AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GZipFile'

Comment: @IshanLiyanage: Python 2 or 3?

Comment: it is python 2, However I worked around it by creating gz file in the same directory as python script and later move it to the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just open the file without specifying a directory hierarchy (just do gzip.open("file.txt.gz"))?. Seems to me like that works. You can always copy the file to another location, if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your current working directory to your output folder, you can then call gzip.open("file.txt.gz") and the gz file will be created without the hierarchy

```
import os
import gzip
content = "Lots of content here"
outputPath = '/home/joe/file.txt.gz'
origDir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(outputPath))
f = gzip.open(os.path.basename(outputPath), 'wb')
f.write(content)
f.close()
os.chdir(origDir)
```