# How can I stop Python's gzip from making sub directories?

Tags: python, gzip

this is probably a simple mistake on my part, but I can't quite figure out how to compress a file without making lots of sub-directories.

Here is how I am doing it:

```
f_in = open(r'C:\cygwin\home\User\Stuff\MoreStuff\file.csv', 'r')
gzip_file_name = r'C:\cygwin\home\User\Stuff\MoreStuff\file.csv.gz'
f_out = gzip.open(gzip_file_name, 'w')
f_out.writelines(f_in)
f_out.close()
```

The problem is, when I decompress that `.gz` file, I don't get just the `csv` file, but rather a long chain of directories that finally end with the csv file.
e.g. `cygwin\home\User\Stuff\MoreStuff\file.csv`

My workaround looks a bit like this:

```
current_dir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(r'C:\cygwin\home\User\Stuff\MoreStuff') 
f_in = open('file.csv', 'r')
gzip_file_name = 'file.csv.gz'
f_out = gzip.open(gzip_file_name, 'w')
f_out.writelines(f_in)
f_out.close()
os.chdir(current_dir)
```

I don't know if it is a good idea to keep changing the current directory (especially since I might have multiple files to compress).

So, is there a way to not make those sub directories? (I couldn't find anything that discussed this in the offical [docs](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/gzip.html) ).

Note: I am using Windows, but I do need this to be portable. I am also using Python 2.4.

Thanks for your time.

edit: I see the sub directories when I open the compressed file in WinRar or even in 7zip. If I do it with `chdir`, then I no longer see those sub directories.

Comment: "The problem is, when I decompress that .gz file, I don't get just the csv file, but rather a long chain of directories" - how exactly are you decompressing it?

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1466443/1062948) answer. The corresponding question is almost identical to yours.

Comment: Also, this appears to have been fixed in later versions of Python. Please see [this](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/gzip.py?r1=72458&r2=75935) diff entry in the Python source code which fixes [Issue 4750](http://bugs.python.org/issue4750). Can you upgrade to Python 2.7?

Comment: Oh thanks @crayzeewulf . I will try out the method in that other question in just a second. As for an upgrade, I could do it, but to be honest, I have no idea if the client will upgrade as well. Thanks, that is a very interesting diff.

Comment: I cannot recreate the problem on Windows using Python 2.7.3. Note, in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html#examples-of-usage) they show the input and output files being opened in binary mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466287/python-gzip-folder-structure-when-zipping-single-file/1466443#1466443) to the previous question that crayzeewulf provided worked just fine.

This is likely only a problem in older distributions of Python. According to that [diff](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/gzip.py?r1=72458&r2=75935) (also provided by crazyzeewulf), this was changed in newer versions, so you likely won't be able to reproduce this problem in Python 2.7.

Thanks for your help everyone.